# Cannot call show method in UnityAds Using SwiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, unityads

I am trying to show unity ads in my ios project. I am using SwiftUI (Not `AppDelegate`, not `Storyboard`). There are not much examples on the web, and the little of them there are old and does not support showing ads with swiftui. Even the unity documentation website does not support it yet. please help me, I get this error from my show ads method and the code won't build: `Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'`

```
import SwiftUI
import UnityAds

//Initialize Unity ads here
UnityAds.initialize("307659", testMode: true)

func loadInterstitial_UnityAds(){
    if UnityAds.isInitialized(){
        UnityAds.load("video")
    }
}
func showAds_Unity(){
    UnityAds.show(UIViewController, placementId:"307659", showDelegate: nil)
}
```

Comment: That error isn’t related to SwiftUI it is telling you that you are trying to use the type of the uiviewcontroller instead of the value of the uiviewcontroller.

Comment: so how can i get the value of the uiviewcontroller?

Comment: By “initializing” one, this can be done in many way depending on context. You can’t provided any context.

Comment: please can you just help me out with some code example to follow please?

Comment: I don’t have any i would if I did, I don’t use Unity ads but like I said context is missing someone that is familiar with the API might be able to narrow down the options but at this point it is all speculation. What does the parent look like are you using storyboards, uiviewcontrollers, etc.

Comment: No I am not using storyboards, i am using swift ui . alright, thanks anyway.

Comment: We’ll UIKit has to be converted to a SwiftUI View using UIViewController or UIViewControllerRepresentable

Comment: alright I will research on that and try it out .